# how do I change timezone of a linux process

Tags: c, linux

I have a program which contains a time syncing module.
The module syncs time with a new timezone and a timestamp.
It changes timezone to the new one by setting up /etc/timezone and /etc/localtime at first, and then set system time using the timestamp.

I tried two methods to set the system time:

```
int set_time(uint64_t ts) {
#if 0
    //first method
    struct timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = ts;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;
    if (settimeofday(&tv, NULL) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
#else
    //second method
    char cmd[256];
    snprintf(cmd, sizeof(cmd), "date -s @%lld", ts);
    if (system(cmd) != 0) {
        return -1;
    }
#endif
    return 0;
}
```

Both method doesn't work as I intended.
After call to this function, the system time is changed according to the timestamp and the new timezone, but the date time printed in the program seems still using the old timezone.(I use the api time and localtime_r to get the current date time.)
However, after I restart the program, the date time printed in the program start to become the same to the system time.

What I want is the date time in the program became the same as the system time after I call the time syncing apis.

Comment: We cannot reproduce the problem with the incomplete program. Please [edit] your question and create a [mre].

Comment: Time is always UTC.  timezone is only needed for conversion to or from a string.  The value of TZ in the environment of the process controls conversion for most library calls.

Comment: Aside: `uint64_t ts` does not match `%lld`.  Use `"%" PRIu64` from `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: To change the time used by a process, you typically need to (a) change the environment variable `TZ` by calling `putenv` or `setenv` and (b) call `tzset()`.

Comment: Also, to "set a new timezone", do not call `settimeofday`.  If right now it's 07:30 EST, and I want to "change my clock" to CST, I would *not* call `settimeofday` to change the clock, nor would I use `system` to invoke the `date` command to set the clock.  Instead, I would change my `TZ` variable to "America/Chicago", and then all time-related functions would suddenly start saying 6:30.  This is because, as @stark said, Linux always maintains UTC internally, and converts to the local time zone only on output.

Comment: If the system's clock is wrong (the actual time is 7:30, but the system is displaying 7:35), only then might you need to call `settimeofday` to set the system clock.

Comment: You said "The module syncs time with a new timezone and a timestamp".  So are you trying to set a time zone, or a timestamp, or both?

Comment: If the answer is "both", then I assume you're receiving some kind of data message "the time is now X in timezone Y", and you're trying to update your system's clock based on that information.  If the problem is that zone Y might not be the system's default time zone, then you will need to first change the time zone to Y, then convert the timestamp X, then set the clock.

Comment: Or, instead of changing the system's time zone, you might be able to use the semistandard `mktime_z` function to convert timestamp X to UTC (suitable for passing to `settimeofday`), using timezone Y, but *without* trying to change `TZ` or the system's default timezone.

Comment: The code you've shown should work to set the time.  But you haven't shown how you're "changing timezone to the new one by setting up /etc/timezone and /etc/localtime at first".  That's where your problem is.

Comment: If you have one program that is (a) making changes to /etc/localtime and /etc/timezone, (b) converting a time representation to `time_t` and finally (c) setting that new time using `settimeofday`, your problem is probably that step (b) is still using the process's old time zone, unaffected by step (a).

Comment: Typical C libraries these days use a TZ data file to convert between universal time and a timezone unless the process's `TZ` environment variable is set to an old "POSIX-style" TZ format string (such as `"EST5EDT"`). If the `TZ` variable is set to an "Olson-style" TZ string (such as `"America/New_York"`) if will use a TZ data file referenced by the identifier. If `TZ` is not set, it will use a default TZ data file /etc/localtime if it exists, otherwise it will use UTC. ...

Comment: Not all C libraries notice when the underlying TZ data file changes while the process is running and may continue to use the old data if the TZ environment variable value is unchanged. That may explain the symptoms you are seeing. You may be able to force the C library to reload the TZ data by calling `tzset()`.

Comment: Thanks for all your help!  I changed /etc/timezone and /etc/localtime for the new timezone, but didn't know that I should use tzset to reload the TZ data for the process. Calling the function tzset after modify the tzfile solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want your libc to re-read time zone information from /etc while your program is running, the simplest way is:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

...
unsetenv("TZ");
tzset();
```

Explanation (man tzset):

> The tzset() function initializes the tzname variable from the TZ
> environment variable. ... If the TZ variable does not appear in the
> environment, the system timezone is used.  The system timezone is
> configured by copying, or linking, a file in the tzfile(5) format to
> /etc/localtime.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, the function tzset is just what I want.